# MariaDB file locations

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Till about an hour ago I had been assuming that MariaDB writes all of its data to the `/var/lib/mysql` folder. However, I just activated loggin in the `my.conf` file to read

`log_error = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log`

and then started + stopped the server.  I was exepecting to see an aerror log at

`/var/log/mysql.log` and sure enough, it was there.  What surprised me though was finding

- mariadb-bin.000001
- mariadb-bin.index
- mysql.log

all three owned by memcache:mlocate.  I have to admit that this makes little sense to me.  What are the two mariadb-* files?  Can they be safely deleted?  Why are they owned by the memcache user, not by mysql?

I'd be most obliged to anyone who might be able to explain.

Comment: they're the binary log files by the looks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ownership is probably due to the ownership of the directory.  Did you install memcached previously?  As long as mariadb has adequate permissions on the files, there is no problem.

`mariadb-bin.000001` is the "binlog" for replication.  `mariadb-bin.index` probably relates to replication, too.  `cat` it if it is small.

If you don't have `log_bin = ON`, then those files will mostly sit idle.  (See `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'log_bin';`)

I would not delete the files; they will just come back when you restart mariadb.

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned the context in my question - the MariaDB instance is in a Docker container with `var/lib.mysql` mapped on to a folder on the host. The ownership issue was actually what I saw when I inspected the host folder. From within Docker the owner is MySQL. On the host I had installed Memcached prior to MariaDB which probably accounts for the userid being interpreted wrong there.